# Why is IMAP mail not being stored on server in Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, imap

I am trying to move someone onto a new PC.  I have discovered that although the account is clearly an IMAP account, the files are **being stored locally rather then on the server**  - And I don't know why or how to fix this or move the email!

Even when I try and create a new IMAP account and drag and drop the mail folders they still get stored locally, rather then on the server.

Does anyone know why this behaviour occurs, and, more importantly, how I can get (a copy of) the email onto the new server [which is in the cloud] ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see "this computer only" in the folder name?

Is that all emails are downloaded to Outlook client and removed from web mail?

To further test this issue, we can exit Outlook client and then directly receive new emails on the web mail.

I’d like to recommend you back up mailbox first to avoid data loss. And then create a new profile in case some personal settings are corrupted. To do this, please go to Control Panel > Mail > Show Profiles > New. Follow the steps to create a new profile.

Comment: Thank  you for your attempt at assistance.  (Please be aware though that these are questions, not an answer, so they really need to be  be in the comments box, not here).  I only see "This computer only" for 1 of the folders, but all have the issue.  Webmail is not involved, and the emails do not exist on the mail server - only in Outlook.   Even dragging them to another IMAP account did not work!